# Doctrine2 custom hydrator for single entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have an entity that requires custom hydration logic. I'm trying to create a custom Doctrine2 hydrator for that entity. Project is written with Symfony3, so I wrote a simple one:

```
final class CustomHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        return array_map(function(array $data) {
            // I'm doing that custom logic here
            $computedData = /* ... */
            return new EntityClass($computedData);
        }, $this->_stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }
}
```

That hydrator was registered in `config.yml`:

```
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      hydrators: [CustomHydrator]
```

Unfortunately it is not called anywhere and I failed to find any documentation that would explain the process of hooking hydrators in Doctrine.

The question is: **how to create custom Doctrine hydrator so that a single entity or a subset of mapped entities would be automatically hydrated this way?**

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I was looking to perform the same operation as you. Did you by chance consider Entity Events to do post load logic?
[Entity Listeners Documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/events.html#entity-listeners)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could create a second entityManager set the default hydrator there, and process those entities with it?

```
orm:
  entity_managers:
    default:
      ...
    myCustom:
      ...
```

Comment: Of course I could, but this goes against what I'm trying to achieve. The ultimate answer is that it can't be done the way I want it in Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration in your `config.yml`:

```
orm:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            hydrators:
                CustomHydrator: \Your\Namespace\To\CustomHydrator
```

Then, in your repository (or wherever you're retrieving your entities), you should make your own queries and use your hydrator in the `getResult` method:

```
$query->getResult('CustomHydrator');
```

In addition, a question has already been asked on how to change Doctrine default hydrator if you need your hydrator to be called at every query: [How to set the default hydrator in Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064488/how-to-set-the-default-hydrator-in-doctrine)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to find a way to force Doctrine to hydrate this entity *automatically*, without mentioning hydrator name. There is a project that has dozens of entities and finding every `find*` call is simply not possible at the moment.

Comment: Then, setting the default hydrator as explained in the link should do the trick (never tried it myself, but if it's the default hydrator, I guess even find* methods will use it?)

Comment: So it's not possible to create a hydrator for the entity directly? Do I need to create my own global hydrator for the whole `EntityManager`?

Comment: I think so. If you need this hydrator for that entity only, I suggest that you create an abstract repository overriding the `find*` methods to make queries using this hydrator, and to make the repositories of the entities that need to use this hydrator extend this abstract repository. It seems a little messy, but it's the best solution I can think of right now according to your needs.